Android - How to remember the device permission
I have (non-rooted) android tablet and I developed MAUI application to run on it. This application (tablet) is to be communicating with embedded system using FTDI cable.
The application is supposed to be running all the time and user can attach and reattach the FTDI cable, without closing the app (only the app status updates to online/offline). I want android to remember this device.
solution 1:

UsbManager.requestpermission()

Issue: it will ask user for permission every time FTDI is re-connected. (Not acceptable)
solution 2:

Using intent filter

Issue: It remembers the device but when re-attached but it also triggers the application, crashing the current one. The application is supposed to be running all the time and user should attach/reattach cable without any interrupt.
Below are some details about my implementation
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.usb.host" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USB_PERMISSION" />
    <application>
        <activity android:name=".UsbActivity"
                    android:directBootAware="true"
                  android:exported="true">
             
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED"
                    android:resource="@xml/device_filter" />

        </activity>
    </application>

It triggers this dialogue when reattached
Allow app "MyAPP" to access FT232R USB UART?
[checkmark]Always open myApp when FT232R USB UART is connected
Cancel            OK

I am aware that action triggers the UsbActivity but honestly, I do not even want it to. Just give the permission and that's it.
Even my MainActivity does not really contain anything
[Activity(Theme = "@style/Maui.SplashTheme", MainLauncher = true, LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTask...]
public class MainActivity : MauiAppCompatActivity
{}

Using UsbActivity like this does not create new object or hit breakpoint at OnCreate() OnResume() ...
namespace my.app
{
    [BroadcastReceiver(Enabled = true, Exported = true)]
    [IntentFilter(new[] { UsbManager.ActionUsbDeviceAttached, "my.app.USB_PERMISSION" })]
    public class UsbActivity : Activity
    {
        public UsbActivity(){...}
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle? savedInstanceState){...}
    }

These are few of the relevant discussions that I have read through
USB device access pop-up suppression?
bypass android usb host permission confirmation dialog
Android USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED persistent permission
